# multiple residue using nest

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, recursion

Is there a simple way to define a multi-dimensional residue computation starting from `Residue` function? This should be used within a function where the number of dimensions $d$ is an argument, so the new `multi-Residue` function should take as input the function $f$ and the point $y \in \mathbb C^d$, and be able to deal with different choices of $d$, to compute

$$ \operatorname{Res}_{x = y} f(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \prod_{i=1}^d \frac{d x_i}{x_i} $$

my attempt:

```
Nest[Residue[f, {Subscript[x, #], Subscript[y, #]}] &, 1, k]
```

Say I would like to get something like (for $d=2$)

```
Res[Res[f(x1,x2),{x2,y2}],{x1,y1}]
```

More in general, supposing a function $g(a,b,c)$ is given, I'm looking for the nested iterations $g(a,x_1,y_1)$, then $g(g(a,x_1,y_1),x_2,y_2)$ and so on.

Comment: This is rather a math stuff (see The theory of residues of analytic functions of several complex variables in https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Residue_of_an_analytic_function  for info) than an MMA stuff.

Comment: @user64494 I understand your point, but suppose I'd like to get something like the above..